# JWT for Angular2 and Laravel

Tags: laravel, angular, jwt, shibboleth

Is there any plugin that uses JWT for authentication with Laravel and angular? The authentication should be done by a 3rd party like Shibboleth.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. I suggest you to read our [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide

Comment: Request help to recommend tools or libraries is 'off topic' in SO